# Aggregate and concatenate strings without duplication

Tags: sql, oracle11g, aggregate-functions

I want to aggregate strings and concatenate them. This is example of what I am using

```
SELECT deptno, LISTAGG(ename, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ename) AS employees
FROM   emp
GROUP BY deptno;

    DEPTNO EMPLOYEES
---------- --------------------------------------------------
        10 CLARK, CLARK,KING,MILLER, MILLER
        20 ADAMS, ADAMS, ADAMS, FORD,JONES,SCOTT,SMITH
        30 ALLEN,BLAKE,JAMES,MARTIN,MARTIN,TURNER,WARD

3 rows selected.
```

But I want results without duplication in concatenated strings.

Desired results:

```
    DEPTNO EMPLOYEES
---------- --------------------------------------------------
        10 CLARK,KING,MILLER
        20 SMITH,FORD,ADAMS,SCOTT,JONES
        30 ALLEN,BLAKE,MARTIN,TURNER,JAMES,WARD

3 rows selected.
```

**EDIT:** so in example below there are some "Employeer names with comma". It is using the proposed answer with regular expression:

```
with emp as (
select 10 as deptno, 'clark,1' as ename from dual
union all
select 10, 'clark,1' from dual
union all
select 10, 'clark,1' from dual
union all
select 10, 'bob' from dual
union all
select 10, 'bob' from dual
union all
select 10, 'don' from dual
union all
select 20, 'tim,2' from dual
union all
select 20, 'tim,2' from dual
union all
select 20, 'tim,2' from dual
union all
select 20, 'jack' from dual
union all
select 20, 'mark' from dual
)
SELECT e.deptno, --LISTAGG(e.ename, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY e.ename) AS employees,
RTRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(listagg (e.ename, ',') 
                     WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY e.ename),
                     '([^,]+)(,\1)+', '\1'),
                     ',') AS employees
FROM   emp e
GROUP BY e.deptno;
```

The results of this query are not  correct:

[image]

Comment: I have already answered similar question here [Distinct LISTAGG that is inside a subquery in the SELECT list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817195/distinct-listagg-that-is-inside-a-subquery-in-the-select-list)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but it's not the solution I would prefer.

Comment: Why? That solution is quite optimal as it would scan the table only once. Using a subquery to filter duplicates needs another table scan.

Comment: Yes, it's quite clever. Your solution depends on separation character `,`. But my data strings could contain comma and the results would be falsified.

Comment: @LalitKumarB Do you know how to fix it ? It would be perfect with some workaround.

Comment: That solution takes care of comma delimited values. If it is not giving you desired output, could you please add more details to your question.

Comment: Wait, how is your original example similar to what you added as an update? Why would you store employee name and a number together in the same column? Employee name as `'clark,1'` makes no sense at all.

Comment: my original example is simplification.

Comment: So yoy have values like `'clark,1'` in the same column?

Comment: yes, i have this sort of data. Of course it is not employeer names. Your solution is perfect for most cases but not for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
FROM   emp
```

with

```
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT deptno, ename FROM  emp)
```

(From a non-Oracle user, but it should work)

Comment: Not an optimal solution since you would scan the table twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use REGEX:

```
SELECT   deptno, 
         rtrim( regexp_replace( (Listagg(ename,',') within GROUP (ORDER BY ename) OVER ()), '([^-]*)(-\1)+($|-)', '\1\3'), '-') within GROUP (ORDER BY ename) AS employees 
FROM     emp 
GROUP BY deptno;
```

Here's a method using crossjoin

```
SELECT DISTINCT deptno, 
                b.enames 
FROM   emp a 
       cross join (SELECT Listagg(ename, '-') 
                            within GROUP (ORDER BY ename) enames 
                   FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT enam ename 
                           FROM   emp)) b
```

Let me know if they work

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not know what your second solution supposed to do. `CROSS JOIN` will return all possible combinations