# distinct listagg in sql view

Tags: sql, oracle, view, listagg

I have a table like this:

```
id  name
1   ben
1   ben
2   charlie
2   dan
2   edgar
3   frank
```

and i want the following columns to be part of an existing view in sql developer:

```
id  names
1   ben
2   charlie,dan,edgar
3   frank
```

I was able to generate the table (id, names) using listagg but i cant add it to the view (most popular error is invalid identifier).

please let me know if more information is needed.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a sub-query to first select only the **DISTINCT** rows before applying **LISTAGG**.

For example,

**Setup**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t
  2      (id int, name varchar2(7));

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT ALL
  2      INTO t (id, name)
  3           VALUES (1, 'ben')
  4      INTO t (id, name)
  5           VALUES (1, 'ben')
  6      INTO t (id, name)
  7           VALUES (2, 'charlie')
  8      INTO t (id, name)
  9           VALUES (2, 'dan')
 10      INTO t (id, name)
 11           VALUES (2, 'edgar')
 12      INTO t (id, name)
 13           VALUES (3, 'frank')
 14  SELECT * FROM dual;

6 rows created.

SQL>
```

**Query**

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT DISTINCT ID, NAME FROM t
  3  )
  4  SELECT ID,
  5    listagg(NAME, ',') WITHIN GROUP (
  6  ORDER BY ID) NAME
  7  FROM DATA
  8  GROUP BY ID;

        ID NAME
---------- -----------------------------
         1 ben
         2 charlie,dan,edgar
         3 frank

SQL>
```

Another way is to **remove the duplicates from the aggregated values** as answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27817597/3989608.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT id,
  2    RTRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(listagg (name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (
  3  ORDER BY id), '([^,]+)(,\1)+', '\1'), ',') name
  4  FROM t
  5  GROUP BY id;

        ID NAME
---------- ---------------------------------------------
         1 ben
         2 charlie,dan,edgar
         3 frank

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks for your help but i was trying to avoid adding another table.

Comment: anyway, it turns out getting all the names in a row takes too long for the view so i'll try a different approach

Comment: @dannylibren Why would you add another table? I created the table for demonstration because you did not provide any test case. Also, I have provided two solutions. First one directly accesses the table, the second one is a subquery. In fact, the first solution completely answers your question. Please mark it as answered.

Comment: All you want is to add the aggregated values to the view. So, all you need to do is, create or replace the view based on the query I gave you.